# disabling a dropdown based on choice in previous radioitem/dropdown in python plotlydash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have 3 chained dropdowns but i want them all to be disabled (not just options, but the dropdown altogether) based on a value in my radioitem. From my code right now:

```py
initialoptions = ["All music", "I choose"]
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='initialoptions',
        options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in initialoptions],
        value="All music",
        style={'textAlign':'center', 'font-family' : 'Roboto',"fontSize" : 14}

@app.callback(
    Output('artistnames', 'disabled'),
    Output('albumnames', 'disabled'),
    Output('songnames', 'disabled'),
    Input('initialoptions', 'value'))
def disable_options(selected_option):
    if selected_option=="All music":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

i would expect that once you press "I choose"
it would return False and otherwise they would stay disabled.
However I cannot seem to get it to disable them altogether, any ideas?
I can  give the dropdowns the disabled=true to begin with but then they won't enable again by pressing the other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

If you want to change 3 outputs at once, the return must give a tuple with 1 return for each output which means the solution is changing

```
return True
    else:
        return False
```

to:

```
return (True,True,True)
    else:
        return (False,False,False)
```